How do I exclude duplicated suggested exports in angular workspace in vscode?
I have an angular workspace which has 2 projects. An application and a library.
The library builds into dist/ on workspace level and provides exports to the application.
Library exports which are distributed are imported/exported inside public-api.js.
As stated here: https://angular.dev/tools/libraries/creating-libraries

How do I get the suggestion to only show the ones inside dist ("shared" in the image) and not from the library itself?
This is my tsconfig:

I expect to only show the include path from the dist folder.
In this case as seen in the picture from "shared" on the right.
Update
24.08.2024
If you import from anywhere other than an angular template, vscode's auto import choses based on the importModuleSpecifier setting and the tsconfig. In my case the first seen in the image above. But if you auto import from a template, even inside template: '<- from here ->' in the @Components obj property, it always choses the relative auto import regardless of any settings or options (The second one in the image above).

In vscode settings search for "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier", select non-relative imports or the one that best suits you.

@OscarLudick This works partially. Importing inside the component.ts imports it from "shared". So the one I want. Importing it from the component.html imports it from the implementation.. So the exact opposite. I tried all possible options of this settings as well as restarting and creating a new component.
